# Can you add preprocessor directives in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, c-preprocessor

I would like to execute some assembly instructions based on a define from a header file.

Let's say in `test.h` I have `#define DEBUG`.

In `test.asm` I want to check somehow like `#ifdef DEBUG` do something...

Is such thing possible? I was not able to find something helpful in the similar questions or online.

Comment: I don't think I understand, _In `test.asm` I want to check somehow like `#ifdef DEBUG` do something..._, preprocessor `#ifdef` is not meant to **execute** a given block of code, but to compile a given block.

Comment: I think it depends on which asm compiler you use, I know that there's some kind of preprocessor directives in nasm but haven't explored much more to tell. What are you compiling your programs with?

Comment: For Microsoft MASM (ML.EXE), there are conditional directives: [MSDN - MASM directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx) . If you can find a copy, there's also a H2INC.EXE utility to convert .h files to MASM .inc files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can run the C preprocessor on your asm file. Depends on your build environment how to do this. `gcc`, for example, automatically runs it for files with extension `.S` (capital). Note that whatever you include, should be asm compatible. It is common practice to conditionally include part of the header, using `#ifndef ASSEMBLY` or similar constructs, so you can have C and ASM parts in the same header.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "asm compatible" ? I just found out that I don't have to include a header anymore but I don't want to make the question more specific that it already is.

Comment: _asm compatible_ means it should only have things in it that are valid in your asm source. For example, it should not have function prototypes, or type definitions. As I said, the file can contain those, if they are protected by appropriate directives so they are not visible when assembling.

Answer (score 7):

The C preprocessor is just a program that inputs data (C source files), transforms it, and outputs data again (translation units).

You can run it manually like so:

```
gcc -E < input > output
```

which means you can run the C preprocessor over .txt files, or latex files, if you want to.

The difficult bit, of course, is how you integrate that in your build system. This very much depends on the build system you're using. If that involves makefiles, you create a target for your assembler file:

```
assembler_file: input_1 input_2
        gcc -E < $^ > $@
```

and then you compile "assembler_file" in whatever way you normally compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure but that is no longer assembly language, you would need to feed it through a C preprocessor that also knows that this is a hybrid C/asm file and does the c preprocessing part but doesnt try to compile, it then feeds to to the assembler or has its own assembler built in.

Possible, heavily depends on your toolchain (either supported or not) but IMO leaves a very bad taste, YMMV.